# YUIDOC - Document params of returned callback

Tags: documentation, yuidoc

How can I properly document a returned callback that returns multiple parameters. Exe:

`return callback(error, success);`

Answer (score 0):

I would document this return value as follows:

```
/**
 * @return {Function} Returns the callback in the form of `callback(error, success)`
 */
```

That is -- use the actual string description of the return statement. (YUIDoc doesn't really have the ability to document what you want explicitly, without describing in text.)